# Probably an easy question on why these two non-linear congruences have the same solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In my lecture notes it says suppose that $(a,p)=1$ , $p$ is an odd prime then the solutions to

$$ax^2+bx+c\equiv0 (modp)$$

are the same as

$$4a(ax^2+bx+c)\equiv 0(modp)$$

Why is this so ?

I had expected that because $(a,p)=1$ then if $p$ is odd it means that we get $(4a,p)=1$ and that in turn it would mean that $4a(a^2+bx+c)\equiv ax^2+bx+c (modp)$ i.e. that $4a$ would be 1 mod p but checking this for $p=3,a=2$ I got that $4a=2mod3$

Comment: $(a,p)=1,\ p$ is odd $\implies (4a,p)=1\implies 4a$ is invertible $\pmod p$

Comment: which means we can divide both sides of a congruence $\pmod p$ by $4a$

Answer (score 2):

The statement $(a,p) = 1 $ implies that $ a \not\equiv 0 \mod p$. Since $p$ is odd also $2 \not \equiv 0 \mod p$, so $2 \cdot 2 \cdot a = 4a \not \equiv 0 \mod p$.

Then $4a \cdot f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p \iff f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p$.

It is worth noting that we use the primality of $p$ only at the end. We only use the primality of $p$ to say that a product is zero iff one of its factors is zero. This follows since the ring $\Bbb Z_p$ is an integral domain exactly when $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $4a(ax^2+bx+c)\equiv 0\pmod p.$  This means $p$ divides $4a(ax^2+bx+c)$.

By [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), since $p$ is prime, this means $p$ divides $4$ or $a$ or $ax^2+bx+c.$

No odd prime $p$ divides $4$, and $(a,p)=1$ means $p$ does not divide $a$,

so we're left with $p$ divides $ax^2+bx+c$; i.e., $ax^2+bx+c\equiv0\pmod p$.

Conversely, if $ax^2+bx+c\equiv0\pmod p$,

then it should be obvious that $4a(ax^2+bx+c)\equiv0\pmod p$.

Thus, the solutions to $ax^2+bx+c\equiv0\pmod p$

are the same as those to $4a(ax^2+bx+c)\equiv0\pmod p$.